# Proper Google docstring for lists

Tags: python-2.7, docstring

I've been using the Google Docstring format described [here](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I'm wondering if there is an agreed upon method for documenting lists of a known type.

I've been using

```
def function(a_list)
    """

    Args:
        a_list (list[dict]): a list of dictionaries
    """
    ...
```

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know about that particular format, but a common way to indicate a list is `type[]`. For what it's worth, it doesn't look like the actual google style guide encourages use of types in that format, but rather just a plain english indication of the type http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the advances in type hinting that didn't exist when I first asked this question I would now defer to that style:

```
from typing import List

def function(a_list: List[dict])
    """

    Args:
        a_list (List[dict]): a list of dictionaries
    """
    ...
```

Comment: I would like to also note that as of python 3.9, one can use `list[dict]` instead of importing the `List` type from `typing` and using that